# Is it possible to declare subclass objects in another subclass?

Tags: c++, parent-child

I am pretty new to computing, especially to C++ and the functionality that it provides. Please be gentle with the bashing :)

I would like to ask if it is possible to declare a subclass object in another subclass. For example, can I have

```
class Shape {
...
};

class Square: public Shape {
..
};

class Cube: public Shape {
...
Square sq1;
...
};
```

I am asking this since there is a fatal error LNK2019 when I tried to compile, but my IDE is not highlighting anything specific.

Comment: You should post a sscce with the full error message. We cannot guess all the subtleties of your code otherwise.

Comment: The link error is unrelated to the member variable.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code per se, see [here](http://cpp.sh/4tlx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. There's nothing particularly different about `Square` than from any other class. Just the fact that it happens to be a subclass of another class makes no practical difference in this context.

Just like you can have:

```
class Shape { ... };

class Square { .. };

class Cube: public Shape { ... Square sq1; ... };
```

You can also have:

```
class Shape { ... };

class Square : public Shape { .. };

class Cube: public Shape { ... Square sq1; ... };
```

Of course, whether something is a subclass of another class changes which methods the class instance has, since it's going to inherit public methods from its superclass.